# Function to open apple maps for driving directions?

Tags: swift, maps, directions

I am constructing an app that features a list of businesses and their locations (locations in coordinate form), and I'd like to provide a button that, when pressed, pushes the user over to Apple Maps and brings up driving directions.

How could I go about doing this?  I've seen similar questions asked on StackOverflow, but they've been referring to mobile web URLS, mine will be native to the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Check out this code.

```
    let placemark : MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: <your coordinate>, addressDictionary:nil)
    //your placemark... Put in the coordinate here
    let mapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    let launchOptions: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking, forKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey)
    //in the lauch options, you can make it driving, walking, or public transportation
    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject])
```